# How to prevent postback while pressing enter key from inside html input textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, postback

Am using html input textbox in .aspx page, when i change values in that textbox and hit enter key means  page get postback. How to prevent this postback other than returning false  in "onkeypress" event.

**Code**:

```
textBox[0].setAttribute("onkeydown", "return (event.keyCode!=13);");
```

Thanks,
Karthik.

Comment: What's the matter with returning false on `onkeypress`?

Comment: For some reason i don't want to use return false in "onkeydown", is there any control like asp:UpdatePanel in HTML to prevent the PostBack?

Answer (score 12):

You need to use javascript to prevent the default behaviour of clicking enter, which is to submit the form. You need to do something like this (and I'm using jQuery here, which is included by default with an ASP.Net app):

```
$('input[type="text"]').keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  });
```

Comment: is it necessarry to use event.preventDefault() ?

Comment: @fubo Yes, as the default behaviour would be to initiate a postback. You need to prevent this.

Comment: ok - in my case the return false prevents a postback. anyway good solution +1

Comment: You also need to select other input elements, like radio and checkboxes, as the form will submit if those elements are selected and the user then hits the enter button.
$('input[type="text"], input[type="radio"], input[type="checkbox"]').keydown...